# How to download a tar.gz extension?

Tags: virtualbox, tar

I am trying to download the Open journal System (OJS) in Ubuntu 16.04 in Oracle VM Virtual Box, but the following is happening......

```
root@zesan-VirtualBox:/var/www/html# tar zxvf  /home/user/Downloads/ojs-3.0.2.tar.gz

tar (child): /home/user/Downloads/ojs-3.0.2.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

root@zesan-VirtualBox:/var/www/html#
```

Comment: Sometimes the file is not yet fully downloaded. Then untar will fail

Comment: "/home/user/Downloads/". Please don't tell me you forgot to change "user" to your username"? It should be "/home/$USER/Downloads/"

Comment: @Rinzwind That won't help, he's working as *root*.

Answer (score 1):

"No such file or directory" usually means exactly this - the file is not in the place you're looking for it, or has some different name. Check with the `ls` command if the path and the file exist:

```
# ls /home/user/Downloads
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you actually downloaded it? Tar is used for unpacking it and it seems you don't have it in your `Downloads` folder. For downloading you would use wget e.g.

```
wget http://this-is-my-download.link/path/to/ojs-3.0.2.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you guys for all the suggestions, it did work after proper download.